# How to get the selected entry in WebDynpro ABAP table?

Tags: abap, webdynpro

I have a webdynpro containing a table displaying numerous lines. After the user clicks the delete button I want to delete the selected line of the table.

My problem right now is, that I don't know how to implement this in the event-call.

How can I identify the selected line of the table?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got the solution:

In the button event implement the following, to access the node and finally the id-value:

```
method ONACTIONZSS10_15_ONDELETE .  
  DATA ls_cust type wd_this->element_IT_Cust.
  DATA lo_nd_cust TYPE REF TO if_wd_context_node.
  DATA lo_el_cust TYPE REF TO if_wd_context_element.

  " Get the selected element
  lo_nd_cust = wd_context->get_child_node( name = 'IT_CUST' ).
  lo_el_cust = lo_nd_cust->get_element( ).

  " Get the attributes of the node-element
  lo_el_cust->get_static_attributes(
    IMPORTING
      static_attributes = ls_cust ).

  " Call the delete-function
  CALL FUNCTION 'ZSS10_15_CUST_FM_DELETE'
    EXPORTING
      custid        = ls_cust-ID
            .
endmethod.
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "table" you mean an editable ALV, there's a preset function for this. Take a look at http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04s/helpdata/EN/5f/ec57c72a1349c8bfdda56d976e9399/frameset.htm and http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04s/helpdata/EN/5f/ec57c72a1349c8bfdda56d976e9399/frameset.htm For details on how to process the selection manually, see http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04s/helpdata/EN/5f/ec57c72a1349c8bfdda56d976e9399/frameset.htm.

Comment: you posted 3 times entirely the same link. i bet you walked into the frameset-trap like me some days ago.